# Zsh: lazy load bindkey to a function?

Tags: zsh

I have a zsh script that loads when start new shell with default is zsh.

```
func1() {
  <..check if in a git repo, if not return..>
  <..code here..>
}
zle -N func1
bindkey '\eo' func1
```

The above function `func1` is triggered when press `Alt-o`. This function only loaded when in a `git` repo.

The problem is that the cost of load this function is pretty high and slowing down the shell prompt if it always loaded when start new shell, how to "lazy" - load only when first time trigger `Alt-o`?

Answer (score 1):

`autoload` is the mechanism for delaying the load of functions until they are used; in a `$fpath` directory create a `testfunc` file:

```
% < testfunc
testfunc() {
    sleep 3
    print this is a test function
}
```

and then `autoload` it (and then `zle ...`, if necessary):

```
% grep testfunc ~/.zshrc
autoload -U testfunc
```

it should not be in memory until used:

```
% exec zsh -l
% print $functions[testfunc]
builtin autoload -XU
% testfunc
this is a test function
% print $functions[testfunc]
    sleep 3
    print this is a test function
```

Comment: Thanks, if I trigger for the first time I got this error: `testfunc: no such file or directory: testfunc`, and then trigger for the second time, `testfunc` run as expected, Is there reason why?

Comment: not without more detail on your exact setup. try from a `zsh -f` to clear out any other configuration

Comment: What exactly that depends on setup can cause the issue? I tried `zsh -f` then manually set fpath `export fpath=(~/.zsh/functions $fpath)`, then `autoload -U testfunc`, and run `> testfunc`. Still the same error for first time run.

Comment: try `strace` or the like then. `autoload` is how all the tab completions get loaded, and I've never seen the error you report before

Comment: Does `zsh -f` ignores `.zshrc` file? I have `fpath` exported in `.zshenv`. Really confused but this task seems to be critical to my workflow, so I'll really appreciated if you can point it out a little more clearly, I'm normal zsh user, I can't understand some implication.